Can I do tree.command, but for special group of users?
I have a problem. I need to make slash commands that will be displayed only to the administration, while others will not see them. Is there such a possibility?
I can't find this information in Google. Can you help me, please?

Yes you can, but you have to change the permissions directly from Discord.
server settings -> integrations -> manage next to your bot. From there you have the list of slash commands and you can change permissions just like normal channel permissions.
More here https://discord.com/blog/slash-commands-permissions-discord-apps-bots
